# Convert SQL Query to ORM Query Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

Here is SQL Query:

```
SELECT id, ip_src, ip_dst, src_port, ip_proto, sum(bytes) as Traffic
FROM table GROUP BY ip_src, ip_dst, ip_proto 
ORDER BY 6 DESC limit 10;
```

I need to convert it in ORM Query. I know that there are raw sql queries in Django, but I need ORM in order to integrate this query with Chartit addon(Highcharts), which understands only querysets and models.

Got this, but it's not correct

```
Flow.objects.values('ip_src', 'ip_dst', 'ip_proto',
 'bytes').annotate(traffic=Sum('bytes')).order_by('-traffic')[:10]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: don't put `'bytes'` in the `values()` call

Comment: I don't understand why people have voted this question as 'too broad' (and I disagree)... the question is very specific and has a single correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Flow.objects.values('ip_src', 'ip_dst', 'ip_proto').annotate(traffic=Sum('bytes')).order_by('-traffic')[:10]
```